# Android Toggle "Hide/Show Hidden Folders"

Tags: android, hidden

I've just started Android development and would like to write a program to toggle the ability to see hidden folders when a button is hit (instead of having to go into a file manager and manually toggle it).  I've looked around the API, but wasn't able to find anything on hidden folders beyond creating them (or renaming them to change the actual folder's status).  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very appreciative!

My Pseudocode:

```
if (hiddenToggleStatus() == 0) { 
    setHiddenToggleStatus(1);
}
else setHiddenToggleStatus(0);
```

Comment: Android does not have a concept of "hidden folders", other than the Linux convention of sometimes suppressing files and directories whose names begin with `.`. Could you explain in greater detail what you mean by "hidden folders"?

Comment: My wording might not have been proper, sorry.  By "hidden folder", I do mean folders starting with ".".  Inside of my File Manager, I'm able to navigate through my settings to toggle that vision of those folders and I'd like to create a button app to do the same - only with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to implement your own file manager that offers an easier means of toggling whether or not leading-dot files and directories are shown.

You are welcome to implement some utility that adds or removes leading dots from files and directories, thereby perhaps affecting other file manager-style tools.

You have no means of otherwise affecting the behavior of third-party file managers. You did not write those apps; you cannot modify them.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  I've been thinking of the phone as a computer and the built in file manager as a 'settings' menu whereas this is not the case - it is it's own separate app.  This helps me a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2841359: Also, bear in mind that Android does not have a built-in file manager. Some Android *devices* do, but the implementation of those apps is up to the device manufacturers. There's also a ton of file managers up on the Play Store.